# Redirect to IAM Auth API from API gateway from lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have 3 APIs in my API Gateway, all are IAM AUTH enabled. When a request comes to one of the APIs (lets say Redirect API), I have to redirect to one of the other 2 APIs based on some logic.

The Redirect API is now backed by Lambda for logic processing. The Lambda returns a response as follows:

```
{
    'statusCode': 302,
    'headers': {
        'Location': <One of the endpoints>
        <auth headers>
}
```

The API gateway is supposed to follow the redirect and get the data (Tested this without IAM auth). I get a `403` error saying `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. The canonical string should have been <string>. The string to sign should have been <string>`. The weird thing is I have verified the canonical string and string to sign made in my lambda, it matches exactly.

Need some way to solve this issue or being able to redirect to one of the APIs from the Redirect APIs.

Comment: *"The API gateway is supposed to follow the redirect and get the data."*  Highly doubtful.  The redirect will be sent to the browser, which will follow the redirect.  Any auth headers in the Lambda response should be ignored.

Comment: The API gateway will follow the redirect. Tested this without IAM.